# All sites fail with 401 unauthorized

Tags: 14.04, internet, authentication

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and until yesterday everything was fine.
Today I cannot access any site (no matter which browser I use). 
If I start Firefox, it wants to go to: start.ubuntu.com and I get a popup with in the title "Authentication required" and then it says: "A username and password are being requested by http://start.ubuntu.com. The site says: "NET Disk""
If I cancel, I get 401 Unauthorized
Authorization required.

Also if I run an update or upgrade from a Terminal window, I get these messages, for example:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/unity/unity-2d_7.2.4+14.04.20141217-0ubuntu1_all.deb  401  Unauthorized
```

I am connected to the internet. I can ping whichever site I choose and I get a result.
What is causing this and how can I fix it?

```
$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:85:4c:99:e2  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:30374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9332832 (9.3 MB)  TX bytes:9332832 (9.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:21:4e:d8:d3  
          inet addr:192.168.1.14  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:21ff:fe4e:d8d3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34843 errors:182 dropped:64920 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62194 errors:8 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3590980 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:7778713 (7.7 MB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:f87e8000-f87e8100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd comment, except all my rep is wrapped up in a bounty.  Do you have a NAS (network attached storage, e.g. external hard drive plugged into your router)?  Net Disk is a brand of those and it is somehow possible that your port 80 (http) is being routed to it for some reason.  Try going to an https site (e.g. https://news.google.com/) and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: I have identified the external hard disk that is giving the problems. What is strange is that it is only my pc that runs ubuntu that has these problems. Another windows7 pc and a mac use the same network and they are not bothered by this external hard disk. And two days ago my Ubuntu pc also did not have any issues.
Any idea what is causing this and how it can be solved?

Comment: Not really. Is it possible the software/firmware on the hard disk is set to auto-update? Have the Mac and Windows machines rebooted? Maybe the hdd doesn't detect the DHCP server and tries to take over?

Answer (score 0):

With a big thank you to rpierce I can say that his comment did the trick.
I unplugged the external hard drives and it all worked again.
I may have also found out what was causing the problem. The external hard drives are plugged into a wireless router which is connected to the main router/modem.
Ever since I unplugged the cable between the two routers the problem with the http-traffic was solved. But once I plugged the cable back in, the secondary router does not connect to the main one any more.
I suspect it is because the UTP-connector is not installed very well. I guess that may have caused some unwanted traffic.

Thanks again for the quick and very useful reply!